# Eclipse Project Reference Hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I am working on creating pluggable modules in my Product and have thus created multiple Java projects in my eclipse Workspace. I wish to maintain a proper hierarchy of project references so suppose the project works something like this:

- Core Project (refers nothing).

  Project 1 (refers Core Project).

  Project 2 (Refers to Project 1 as well as Core Project).

Now in the Build path of Project 1 I have added Core Project in the Projects tab.
Now in the Build path of Project 2 I have added only the reference of Project 1 assuming that since Project 1 refers to Core Project, the references for Core Project will be available in Project 2 as well. But unfortunately Core Project is not visible to Project 2.

Would love any help I can get in achieving such a hierarchy if it is possible in Eclipse.

Comment: are you not using a dependency management solution, like Maven?

Comment: No, as of now there is no dependency management solution in the projects.

Comment: i dont know why core is not available for project 2, are you getting any error?

Comment: @pappu_kutty - yeah the build shows compile-time error and on clicking the "Fix project setup.." option in the hints, it tells me to add Core to build path of Project 2

Comment: is it project 2 is of java nature, if not go to properties> project facets > check java

Comment: all the three are java projects. I even did a small PoC creating 3 projects and the same issue exists here itself with the core not being accessible beyond the project which directly depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use maven and m2e plugin (eclipse maven integration)

1. Add core dependency to project 1
2. Add project 1 dependency to project 2

Let maven and eclipse do their job, everything will work like a charm..

Comment: Ok but for the time being let us assume we cannot use maven or m2e plugin(we are not using maven in the project). So considering this limitation, what are the possible options do you think I have?

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you want to access "core" classes from project 2, it is not a mistake to reference core as a dependency of project 2

Comment: I agree that it's not a mistake to add core as a dependency and eventually we might do just that to get the project to compile and it will. But still the question remains unanswered as to why the reference of Core is not accessible to Project 2 via. Project 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I posted the query to bug.eclipse.org and finally got the answer to it. Here is the link to the solution - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472030

Goto the Order and Export tab of Project 1 in Configure Build path menu and check the checkbox beside Core Project. And then it is visible to the Project 2.
This is so because Eclipse does not export its dependencies by default.